# Memory release problem with cvHoughLines2

Tags: java, opencv

I have a problem with javaCV:

```
CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

CvSeq lines = cvHoughLines2( houghInputImage, storage.getPointer(),
     cv.CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, rho, Math.PI/theta, threshold, param1, param2 );

// ...

storage.release();
```

This code doesn't release the memory. Used memory groving until my laptop die. 
If I comment out the cvHoughLines2 line then there is no problem, used memory doesn't groving.

Can you help me why it's happening? What do I wrong?

My environment: XP Home, OpenCV 2.1, JavaCV20100730, JRE6.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with JavaCV as well. I am not sure where the exact problem lie, but I solved it by replacing the following line:

```
storage.release();
```

with:

```
cvClearMemStorage(lines.storage);
```

It seems to be important to release the memory from the storage object *within* the resulting CvSeq rather than on the one you originally passed in.

Hope this of some help!

Answer (score 0):

Storage handling is working correctly in OpenCV so may be the problem can be found in JavaCV.

I assume that you call the code above in a loop. You should try to move the storage creation and release outside the loop and you may only loose memory at the end of the run.